# Как введёные данные в QLineEdit передать в поток QThread и в дальнейшем работать с этими данными?

Tags: python, многопоточность, pyqt, qthread, qlineedit

Как при нажатие кнопки введённые данные в `QLineEdit` передать в поток `QThread` и в дальнейшем работать с этими данными в методе `run()`?

Допустим я ввёл цифру **`5`** и с этой цифрой в методе `run()` запустился цикл.

```py
#цикл
while i < 1500:
    print(i)
    i = i + 2
```

---

**main.py**:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(644, 387)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 110, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 220, 75, 43))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))


class TheThread(QtCore.QThread):
    threadSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def run(self):
        while i < 1500:


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.thread = TheThread()

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.func1)  

    def func1(self):
        self.thread.start()


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)  
    window = ExampleApp() 
    window.show()  
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(644, 387)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 110, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 220, 75, 43))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))


class TheThread(QtCore.QThread):

    threadSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)                     # int

    def __init__(self, num):                                  # +++
        super(TheThread, self).__init__()  
        self.num = num

    def run(self):
        while self.num < 1500:
            self.threadSignal.emit(self.num)
            QtCore.QThread.msleep(10)
            self.num += 2


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)           # +
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 140, 113, 20))

#        self.thread = TheThread(int(self.lineEdit.text()))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.func1)  

    def func1(self):
        self.thread = TheThread(int(self.lineEdit.text()))          # + (int(self.lineEdit.text()))
        self.thread.threadSignal.connect(self.funcPrint)            # +
        self.thread.start()

    def funcPrint(self, num):                                       # +
        self.label.setText("---> {}".format(num))

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)  
    window = ExampleApp() 
    window.show()  
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

> А как сделать если у тебя несколько QLineEdit? То есть передать методу run введённые значения в QLineEdit.

Если вы передаете в качестве значений цифры, то правильнее использовать виджет `QSpinBox`.
Попробуйте:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(644, 387)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 110, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 220, 75, 43))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))


class TheThread(QtCore.QThread):

    threadSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str, int)    

    def __init__(self, n_1, n_2):                        
        super(TheThread, self).__init__()  
        self.n_1 = n_1
        self.n_2 = n_2

    def run(self):
        while self.n_1 <= 1500  or  self.n_2 <= 1500:
            if self.n_1 <= 1500:
                self.threadSignal.emit("n_1", self.n_1)
                QtCore.QThread.msleep(10)
                self.n_1 += 2
            if self.n_2 <= 1500:
                self.threadSignal.emit("n_2", self.n_2)
                QtCore.QThread.msleep(10)
                self.n_2 += 2


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel("---> .... ", self.centralwidget)           
        self.label_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 140, 113, 20))
        self.spinBox_2 = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(minimum=0, maximum=9999)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel("---> .... ", )
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.func1)  

        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.label_1, 0, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.spinBox_2, 1, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.label_2, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 5, 0, 1, 2) 


    def func1(self):
        n_1 = int(self.lineEdit.text())
        n_2 = self.spinBox_2.value()
        self.thread = TheThread(n_1, n_2)          
        self.thread.threadSignal.connect(self.funcPrint)            
        self.thread.start()

    def funcPrint(self, text, num):    
        if text == "n_1": self.label_1.setText("---> {}".format(num))
        if text == "n_2": self.label_2.setText("---> {}".format(num))

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)  
    window = ExampleApp() 
    window.show()  
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо!!!А как сделать если у тебя несколько QLineEdit?Тоесть передать методу run введённые значения в QLineEdit.

Comment: @sens250  я добавил обновление в свой ответ.

Comment: Ещё раз огромное спасибо)